# Permanent exception during Flutter app execution on Android device and emulator

Tags: android, flutter

I am working on a Flutter app that works fine, but there is a log error message that I don't where it cames from and I would like to remove it. It is very disturbing then it is shown continously and I can't identify the source of that issue.

Here you have the error message:

```
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lv@b39373f
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1493)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1653)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:703)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516047@20.45.16 (040308-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516047@20.45.16 (040308-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at lw.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516047@20.45.16 (040308-0):9)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at lg.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516047@20.45.16 (040308-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at eg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516047@20.45.16 (040308-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker( 1715):     at iz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204516047@20.45.16 (040308-0):5)
```